# Build and add children in performLayout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making a skill tree package and I'm wanting to have a robust api for users to alter the appearance of edges between nodes. For that, I want the signature of an edgeBuilder to contain some layout information of the from and to nodes it connects. For example, I could pass through to the builder the angle an imaginary straight line from one node to another makes. This angle could then be used to rotate the widgets I have at the ends of edges to properly look like they're pointing at the right things (in the image below, I have a triangle clipper that is just always pointed down).

[image]

I have this structure for laying out the children (both edges and nodes) inside my multi-child custom RenderObject.

```dart
@override
void performLayout() {
  // ...
  final skillNodeLayout = delegate.layoutNodes(
    loosenedConstraints,
    graph,
    nodeChildren,
  );

  size = skillNodeLayout.size;

  // ...

  delegate.layoutEdges(
    loosenedConstraints,
    skillNodeLayout,
    graph,
    edgeChildren,
    nodeChildren,
  );
}
```

But now I'm curious to know whether Flutter advises against building and adding widgets in the layout phase. The `ContainerRenderObjectMixin` I'm mixing in specifically has methods to add to the list of children such as `adoptChild(child)` or `addAll`.

Can I avoid passing through the edge children to the RenderObject constructor and instead pass them through as a plain list of builder functions I call after the node layout and then add to the RenderObject? Something roughly like this:

```dart
@override
void performLayout() {
  // ...
  final skillNodeLayout = delegate.layoutNodes(
    loosenedConstraints,
    graph,
    nodeChildren,
  );

  size = skillNodeLayout.size;

  final edgeChildren = edgeChildrenBuilders.map((builder) {
    return builder(skillNodeLayout);
  }).toList();

  // Found in the `ContainerRenderObjectMixin`
  addAll(edgeChildren);

  delegate.layoutEdges(
    loosenedConstraints,
    skillNodeLayout,
    graph,
    edgeChildren,
    nodeChildren,
  );
}
```

My worry is that it keeps adding children to the RenderObject every time a performLayout is requested or that this was never the intended way to work with renderObjects.